# How to get HTML's thymeleaf value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN3tc.png)

I send values using model.addAttribute in Spring, so I get values in HTML file well.
and I want to get values in js files so I use document.getElementById but I can't get the value but 0 .. How to get html thymeleaf value in js?
Thank you all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This you find this documented here: https://www.concretepage.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-javascript-inline-example-with-variable

The part which is interesting to you is the following:

```html
<script th:inline="javascript">

/*<![CDATA[*/
  var user = /*[[${session.userName}]]*/ 'User Name';

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

In your case of course instead of `session.userName` you would put your variable name.

```html
<script th:inline="javascript">

/*<![CDATA[*/
  var user = /*[[${modelVariable}]]*/ 'User Name';

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: OMG,,, I appreciate your kindness.. I'm really tired of this problem, but I solve it with your solution. Thanks to you, I can skip to next level. I wish you have a nice day.. Thank you

Comment: Good to hear that! Please mark the correct answer as the accepted answer then. Best Matthias!